# ESP32 using BLE but not WLAN

Tags: wifi, bluetooth-low-energy, esp32, 802.11

I want to build a little gadget which must use BLE to communicate with a smartphone, but should run for at least 24h using a 500mAh battery. So I think to achieve this, I should be able to switch off WLAN, but still use the BLE radio.
Is there any way I can achieve this with an ESP32?

Thx

Comment: You should expand more. Communicate how often? What does it mean *should be able to switch off WLAN* ? Switch it where?

Comment: ESP-IDF supports using BLE without using WiFi, but the chip core doesn't have very nuanced sleep modes, I believe it's more like doing a shutdown and reboot.  It's possible your battery could sustain this anyway, and they're sure cheap enough, but really this sounds more like a task for a conventional BLE MCU (Nordic or the others), which can sustain some usage patterns for months on a little coin cell...

Comment: sorry I was not clear enough. It should send some text over BLE when a button is pressed - nothing else. I need one analog in and a BLE-radio. Maybe something like an ATmega328P with BLE would be better?